# Github still shows differences between branches after sucessfull merge

Tags: git, github, git-merge

Recently I merged a huge pull request (140 commits) from the feature branch to master:

[image]

I can see the merge in the github overiew on the master branch:

[image]

However, when I switch to the feature branch, I can see that feature is 141 commits ahead (today i did another commit on feature) and 1 commit behind master:

[image]

And now the main problem is, I cannot merge the change I did today on feature to master:

[image]

Because github seems to want to commit again the 140 old commits which were already merged (after some painfull conflict resolving)

How can I sync master and feature again, so they are what they actually are: The difference between them  is **ONLY** the commit on feature from today.

Comment: Have a look at the history of the two branches. Do they both contain the 140 commits you're expecting, and crucially do those commits have identical commit hashes, or just the same content?

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32244878/5520012) is related?

Comment: Did you really merge, or did you do a fake squash merge or rebase merge?

Comment: Yes, looks like you unwittingly squashed the first merge.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like you're using two long-running branches and using a squash merge.  That's a bit of a problem, and here's why.

When Git performs a merge, it considers exactly three points: the two heads you're merging, and a third point, called the *merge base*, which is usually their common ancestor.  The result of the merge is the sum of the changes between the merge base and each head.

If you merge two branches with a normal merge commit, then you create a new common ancestor, so future merges start at that base.  You don't have to worry about conflicts from things you've already merged because Git doesn't even consider them.

When you merge two branches with a squash merge, you create a single commit on one branch that includes all of the changes from the other, but you don't create a new common ancestor.  As a result, Git looks at all the changes on both sides when you try to merge again and you can end up with a lot of conflicts.  This only gets worse if you keep squash merging the two branches.

As a result, you really *must* use a normal merge commit to integrate two long-running branches unless you really want to resolve lots of conflicts all the time.  Squash merges won't work here.

If `feature` doesn't need to be long-running, then simply recreate it from `master`.  Git is great at creating feature branches that you can then throw away once they're merged.  That's the simplest way to solve this problem.  Since you have a commit on it that needs to be included, then just follow the steps similar to those eftshift0 outlined:

```
$ git checkout feature
$ git rebase --onto master HEAD^
# optionally:
$ git push origin +feature
```

Otherwise, here's the easiest way to solve this problem.  Take the commit on `master`  immediately before your squash merge and call it `A`.  Take the commit on `feature` that you merged and call it `B`.

```
$ git checkout -b temp A
$ git merge B
$ git checkout master
$ git merge temp
```

This creates a branch called `temp` which looks exactly like the squash merge, but with a real merge commit, and then merges it into `master`.  This merges is a no-op because both sides are completely identical, so you don't have to resolve any conflicts.  However, both sides now share a new common ancestor on which future merges can be based, which solves the problem.  You can then use normal merge commits when integrating the two branches.

Comment: Many thanks for the detailled explanation, things are much clearer now. I followed the first suggestion including the optional step. Then, on github, I created the PR again, this time the PR looks much better. But then I was a bit irritated that Github offered the "Squash and merge" option as a default instead of the "Create a merge commit" (or so). Maybe it remembered my wrong decision from the previous PR. I chose the "Create a merge commit". Now master looks fine. But when I switch to feature it says "1 commit behind master". Is that fine? Or should I delete feature now?

Comment: GitHub remembers what type of merge you used last time on this repository; it doesn't know that these are long-running branches that shouldn't use squash merges.  “1 commit behind master” is correct, since `master` has an additional merge commit.  If you don't need it to persist, you can reset it to `master` on your system with `git checkout -B feature master`.

Answer (score 0):

as @matt is saying, you probably didn't merge but squashed or rebased or something. The best you can do then is rebase that single revision on top of the base branch:

```
git checkout feature-branch
git rebase --onto origin/the-base-branch feature-branch~ feature-branch
```

That will put the branch on top of the base branch... you will probably have to force-push if you are using the same branch that you used before to create the PR because that history was not *really* merged into the base branch so a normal push will fail.