# Git Merge and Compare Woes

Tags: git, gitlab

Our project uses *master* as our "production" branch and *staging* as our "testing" branch. The normal flow of operations we desired was for developers to make changes on their development branches (branched off *staging*) and then merge into staging when they are done. We then do Integration type testing on the *staging* branch. If everything passes we wanted to then merge *staging* into master. In theory, *staging* and *master* shouldn't be too different than each other.

Our first shot at trying this, we got into a state where *master* had changes that *staging* did not, and vice-a-versa.

The way we solved this was we merged *master* into *staging* (fixing all the merge conflicts) and then merged *staging* into *master* (fixing all the merge conflicts).

If I do a

```
git compare <hash from master after merge from stagin>..<hash from staging after merge from master>
```

it returns nothing. I take this to mean that all the files are the same. This is what we expected.

However, if I use ... then it returns a ton of stuff.

GitLens (a git extension for VSCode) says the same:

[image]

Now every attempt to merge *staging* into *master* has a bunch of stuff, not just the changes that have been made since the last merge. However I don't believe most of the stuff are actually file differences.

To make maters worse, we have pushed changes into staging since the initial merging.

What do I need to do to go about fixing this?

Comment: Did you always use a "true merge" (merge commit) or did you use any options like "squash merge" or "rebase and fast-forward"?

Comment: We did it through gitlab and I think we squashed the commits. Would that create a problem? Sorry. Pretty new at this.

Comment: Yes, squash merges should never be used to take changes from a branch you aren't immediately throwing away. A "squash merge" isn't really a merge at all, but a strange artificial commit that throws away all the history you've carefully created (can you guess I'm not a fan?) See [git merge squash and recurring conflicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11797904/git-merge-squash-and-recurring-conflicts) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63862271/github-still-shows-differences-between-branches-after-sucessfull-merge/63864551 and many others.

Comment: Ah ok. I thought this was a "clean" way of doing it. 
Would merging master into staging and then staging into master (with out squashing) fix all of this? or did I royally screw it up.

Comment: One of the linked answers has a suggestion of how to recover things; I haven't tried it myself, but it looks logical.